# Ubuntu install restarts every time a manual network connection is configured

Tags: ubuntu

I don't install Ubuntu often. However, I'm now having this issue twice.

The first time, I ignored it, continued my installation with DHCP enabled, then manually configured the network adapter after install.

Now, I'm on a completely different network, completely different hardware, etc. and trying to do a basic installation of Ubuntu server 18.04 again.

I get to the initial stages, the install finds a DHCP address for the network adapter and gives me the ability to reconfigure it at that time. I edit the settings, and specify the network info I want to use for IPv4 after choosing "Manual" for IPv4 Method:
[image]

When I choose to "Save" the settings, the installation immediately restarts back at the first screen and the settings are erased.

This is now the second time I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 with the exact same problem on completely different networks and hardware. I'm 0 for 2 and can't find even a hint of it on the internet about this problem.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: I found this post with no answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124742/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-server-network-configuration-problem-during-setup?newreg=444bcbeb65ab498b92298f80ad9427dc

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. It looks like in `/var/log/installer/subiquity-debug.log` that a Python exception is being thrown.

If it's maybe related to:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1831373
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124742/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-server-network-configuration-problem-during-setup

And maybe fixed in 19.04 installer and will be fixed in 18.04.3 (I haven't tested myself though)

For now, I'm going to download the alternate installer ISO:

- https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer

[image]